# Why does cmd-click on a link not open a new tab in Gmail (Firefox/Mac)?

Tags: gmail, firefox

Why does cmd-click (tap on the trackpad) on a link not open a new tab in Gmail? It used to work 10 years ago or so but hasn't been working for maybe 5 years. Ctrl-click and selecting a "Open link in new tab" works fine in Gmail and cmd-click on links to open them in a new tab works fine everywhere else, including on Google search.

Firefox/Mac. Three different machines and many different versions of Firefox.

Comment: Only GMail (and possibly the odd site that uses some non-standard Javascript links or so). But e.g., SE works fine in this respect.

Comment: I don't have the answer to "why". But if you use cmd+shift+click, it might work how you want it to work.

Comment: @Theodoor Hmm, interesting. But I have Firefox set to open new tabs in the background but this combination opens them in the foreground. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla just released [Firefox 96.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/96.0/releasenotes/) which fixes this issue

> On macOS, command-clicking links in Gmail now opens them in a new tab as expected.

There was a brief discussion on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=29892238) about this that pointed to the [bug discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1739929) and the [ultimate fix](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/0fb0990124cf).